# Why Swift does not append element into array as a value of dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
var returnCarsNumbers = [Int32: [Int32]]()
```

and after fetching from CoreData I have the next value:

```
let carsNumbers = try context.fetch(request) as! [NSDictionary]
```

the result of which looks like(the sample of one object):

```
Optional<NSDictionary>

▿ some : 2 elements
▿ 0 : 2 elements
  - key : carNbr
  - value : 2747543
▿ 1 : 2 elements
  - key : garageNbr
  - value : 40510
```

and now I'm trying to append those elements into my dictionary:

```
_ = carsNumbers.map {
    let garage = $0.value(forKey: "garageNbr") as! Int32
    let car = $0.value(forKey: "carNbr") as! Int32

    returnCarsNumbers[garage] = [card]
}
```

but when I print `returnCarsNumbers` at the end, I get only few elements

```
[117547: [8808224], 922223: [68015677], 21125: [902403], 36247: [2480974], 252983: [20682146], 902497: [66283014], 40510: [2747408], 271520: [22482094]]
```

It seems it replaces the array values with the latest ones and does not append into the array.
Can someone point to my mistake please?
As a results I want to group all cars with the same garage not only one element

Comment: This is not a valid use of `map`.

Comment: Please show real code copied from your actual project and pasted into the question. Do not attempt to type your code into the question.

Comment: Fetch the objects as `Car` (or what the name of the NSManagedObject subclass is) and use `Dictionary(grouping:by:`. `map` is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want, it uses [forEach(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689783-foreach):

```
carsNumbers.forEach {
    let garage = $0.value(forKey: "garageNbr") as! Int32
    let car = $0.value(forKey: "carNbr") as! Int32

    returnCarsNumbers[garage] = (returnCarsNumbers[garage] ?? []) + [card]
}
```

`??` is the [Nil-Coalescing Operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html), it unwraps the optional left operand if it contains a value, or returns a default value (the operand on the right) if a is nil.

In your code `returnCarsNumbers[garage] = [card]` replaces the whole array in the values of `returnCarsNumbers`.